# Adding space to subreference

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, subfig

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
See Figure~\subref*{sf1} for more information.
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Subfig 1]{\label{sf1} Contents of the sub-figure}
\qquad
\subfloat[Subfig 2]{\label{sf2} Contents of the sub-figure}
\caption{A figure}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would like the subreference to be displayed as

> 1. a

Can you help?